# How to code pause in timer in Adobe Flash using ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

Im doing timer in my project. Now i want to add pause function inside my project. I tried to add stop.timer but it didnt work. Anyone know how to add pause and when user resume the timer work back as usual?

```
var endTime:int = getTimer();
endTime += 40*60*1000;  //adjust endTime to 15 minutes in the future.

var countdownTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
countdownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime);
countdownTimer.start();

function updateTime(e:TimerEvent):void
{
  var timeLeft:Number = endTime - getTimer();
  var seconds:Number = Math.floor(timeLeft / 1000);
  var minutes:Number = Math.floor(seconds / 60);

  seconds %= 60;
  minutes %= 60;

  var sec:String = seconds.toString();
  var min:String = minutes.toString();
  if (sec.length < 2) {
    sec = "0" + sec;
  }

  if (min.length < 2) {
    min = "0" + min;
  }

  var time:String = min + ":" + sec;
  countdown.text = time;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be much easier if you just use the one timer and forget about `getTimer()`.

Here is an example with comments:

```
//make the timer tick every second 900 times (so it will run 15 minutes total)
var countdownTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 900);

//listen for the tick
countdownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime);

//listen for the completion of the timer (if you want to do something when all done
countdownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerComplete);

countdownTimer.start();

function updateTime(e:TimerEvent):void
{
  //this will give the seconds left if the delay is 1000ms
  var secondsLeft:Number = countdownTimer.repeatCount -  countdownTimer.currentCount;

  var minutesLeft:Number = Math.floor(seconds / 60);

  //....rest of your code
}
```

Now, anytime you want you can just pause the timer with `countdownTimer.stop();` and resume it with `countdownTimer.start();`

Comment: what if I want to keep continue with getTimer() ? Can you help me?

Comment: I got this error Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 2, Line 62 1120: Access of undefined property timerComplete.

Comment: You need to make a `timerComplete` function should want to use that.  In your question there is nothing about  what you want to do when it's all done.  If you don't need anything to happen when it's finished, just remove the line that listens for TIMER_COMPLETE.

Answer (score 1):

you should simply extend the Timer class.

```
package {
  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
  import flash.events.IEventDispatcher;
  import flash.events.TimerEvent;
  import flash.utils.Timer;
  import flash.utils.getTimer;
  /**
   * The <code>MyTimer</code> class.<br/>
   */
  public class MyTimer implements IEventDispatcher {
    //==========================================================================
    //  Constructor
    //==========================================================================
    /** Constructor */
    public function MyTimer(delay:Number, repeatCount:int = 0) {
      super();
      $timer = new Timer(delay, repeatCount);
      $startTime = NaN;
      $past = NaN;
      $correct = false;
      $timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler, false, int.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    //==========================================================================
    //  Properties
    //==========================================================================
    private var $correct:Boolean;
    private var $past:Number;
    private var $startTime:Number;
    private var $delay:Number;
    private var $timer:Timer;
    //==========================================================================
    //  Public methods
    //==========================================================================
    public function reset():void {
      $startTime = NaN;
      $past = NaN;
      $timer.reset();
    }
    public function stop():void {
      if(!$timer.running)
        return;
      $past = getTimer() - $startTime;
      $timer.stop();
    }
    public function start():void {
      if(isNaN($startTime)) {
        $startTime = getTimer();
      } else {
        $delay = $timer.delay;
        $timer.delay = $timer.delay - ((getTimer() - $startTime) % $timer.delay);
        $correct = true;
      }
      $timer.start();
    }

    public function dispatchEvent(event:Event):Boolean {
      return $timer.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
    public function addEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false,
                                     priority:int = 0, useWeakReference:Boolean = false):void {
      $timer.addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture, priority, useWeakReference);
    }
    public function removeEventListener(type:String, listener:Function, useCapture:Boolean = false):void {
      $timer.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture);
    }
    public function willTrigger(type:String):Boolean {
      return $timer.willTrigger(type);
    }
    public function hasEventListener(type:String):Boolean {
      return $timer.hasEventListener(type);
    }
    //==========================================================================
    //  Event Listeners
    //==========================================================================
    private function timerHandler(event:Event):void {
      if($correct) {
        $timer.delay = $delay;
        $correct = false;
      }
    }
  } // <- end class ->
}
```